# unable to start Rational Software Architect [eclipse]

Tags: eclipse, rational-rsa

I have updated the eclipse [3.6 to 3.7] of rational software architect. After updating it I am unable to start the rational software architect, although the window task manager showing a process with name eclipse but nothing is appearing. When I enabled the consoleLog it showed me following message and it started

```
    C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\bootProfile_278dcaa46b40_91b46910b12
!SESSION 2013-01-24 16:11:27.765 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120208-0800
java.fullversion=JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Windows XP x86-32 jvmwi3260sr9-20110726_87724 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20110726_087724
JIT  - r9_20101028_17488ifx17
GC   - 20101027_AA
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.ibm.rational.rsa4ws.product.v80.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product com.ibm.rational.rsa4ws.product.v80.ide -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.common 4 0 2013-01-24 16:11:30.328
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.0.v20100503 [1630]" could not be resolved. Reason: Another singleton version selected: org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.0.v20110523, Another singleton version selected: org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.0.v20110523
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Could anyone suggest what should I do to achieve the normal startup.

Comment: Is RSA installed as plugin on eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have more versions of same plugins. You should remove older versions. Perhaps it get easier for you to do a clean install of everything.